# display a dynamic button on a net stream in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I am using flex 4.6 to render videos from net streams of other videos. I am using Netstream library. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html Here I am trying to display a button on top of the net stream by following code.

```
var btn:Button = new Button();
btn.label = 'new button';
btn.x = 100;
btn.y = 100;
addElement(btn);
```

But when I compiled the code (MXML) , it just display the Text 'new button'. I have tried this code in a normal page without netstream it displays the button properly. Does anyone know how to fix this issue.

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?  Your code says the button should say "new button" -- isn't that what you expect?

Comment: It just display the text. It can not be identified as a button

Comment: are you sure, the `btn` is on top of the video? Try to set it on top: `setChildIndex(btn, numChildren-1)`

Comment: what is numChildren variable ?

Comment: @AndreLehnert when I am trying to set the setChildIndex , video stream does not display in the page. button also does not display in the page. Any ideas ??

Comment: please post more relevant code. And please explain the display-object-hierarchy of your app.